# Can someone explain this existence quantor defining real numbers?

Tags: logic, real-numbers, logic-translation

In school a teachers of mine gave us his slides and I came across a topic that we didn't really discuss a lot but is important for a test. In the linked image you can see the definition of real numbers but I couldn't really figure out what it means(the part with the existence quantor). It would be very nice if someone could explain what the part below and next to the quaontor means or just translate it into words.

(I'm not the best at English so excuse typos and by existence quantor I mean the big V if the english name is different)

[definition of real numbers image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpRBB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symbol $\vee$ usually means the logical operation '**or**', and anything below an operation symbol means a condition.

> It means the set of all entities $x$ such that *there is* a sequence $(a_n)$ of rational numbers (i.e. $(a_n)\in\Bbb Q^{\Bbb N}$), such that $\lim_na_n=x$.

(at least one of the statements $x=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ holds, when $(a_n)$ runs over $\Bbb Q^{\Bbb N}$.)

Note by the way, that $\pm\infty$ are not real numbers, though this definition might enable them (depending on how exactly $\lim$ was defined).

Comment: So that means a is equal to a rational number to the power of a natural number and n represent the index of a digit in a?

Comment: No, $\Bbb Q^{\Bbb N}$ doesn't denote the set of 'rationals on natural power', rather the set of *sequences* consisting of rational numbers (literally, the set of all *functions* $\Bbb N\to\Bbb Q$), and $a_n$ is the $n$th member of the sequence, an arbitrary rational number. Note that for finite sets $A,B$, the set of functions $A\to B$ has exactly $|B|^{|A|}$ elements, hence the general notation.

Comment: so what does $\Bbb Q^{\Bbb N}$ mean? I'm not the best with operators so your previous answer was a little difficult to understand for me

Comment: The set of all rational sequences.

Answer (score 0):

To me the definition seems to say:
The set of all $x$ such that at least one of the statements "$x$ is the limit of a sequence of rational numbers $(a_n)_n$" is true.

The symbol is a logical disjunction, i.e. an "OR".

Answer (score 0):

It means that every finite (bounded) limit of a sequence of rational numbers is defined to be a real number.

The key is that different sequences can have the same limit, and specifying the conditions for that to be the case.

The prize is that every bounded limit of a sequence of real numbers is then a real number. So you have a system complete under the operation of taking bounded limits.